# Import adding quotes around address value

Tags: dataextensions, import

I've imported a file into a data extension and one of the fields is for ADDRESS in the file there are no quotes but when I import and look at the data extension the output reads ("123 N Main St.")

Any ideas on how to get rid of the quotes?

Answer (score 0):

If you're uploading purely as a CSV, then those quotes won't show up in your CSV file. This post explains it a bit: https://superuser.com/questions/349882/how-to-avoid-double-quotes-when-saving-excel-file-as-unicode

In my experience, I have had to 1) save the file as a tab delimited, 2) replace tab spaces with a pipe/vertical line, and then 3) search for random quotes to remove them.